# Running Windows Server Core in Docker Container

Tags: python, windows, docker

my Linux containers run like a charm, but the change to Windows Server in my Docker container makes me crazy!

My Docker file doesn't build although it is as simple as my linux Dockerfiles:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

#Install Chocolately
RUN @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "(iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex)" 
ENV PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin 

#Install python
RUN choco install -fy python2
RUN refreshenv
ENV PYTHONIOINPUT=UTF-8

RUN pip install -y scipy
```

Some times I was able to Chocolately which results in a fail to install scipy via PIP or curiously starting 5 minutes ago, even the installation of chocolately fails:

```
iwr : The remote name could not be resolved: 'chocolatey.org'
At line:1 char:2
+ (iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex)
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt
   pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe
   ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Here are some specs on my Docker for Windows Installation:

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 3
Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.693.amd64fre.rs1_release.1612
Operating System: Windows 10 Education
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.903 GiB
Name: xxxx
ID: deleted 
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 18
 System Time: 2017-01-31T16:14:36.3753129+01:00
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like there's a networking problem that's preventing your containers from pulling stuff from the internet. Please see these resource: https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/master/windows-server-container-tools/CleanupContainerHostNetworking

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to get refreshenv to work, so I used multiple powershell sessions, I've included in case it is useful to someone in the future.

```
#Install Chocolately, Python and Python Package Manager, each PowerShell session will reload the PATH from previous step
RUN @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex" 
RUN @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "choco install -y python3"
```